# How do you effectively unit test the parameters of dynamic languages?

Tags: parameters, dynamic-languages

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475048/type-of-object-referencies-in-ruby/1475058#1475058) hit a nerve with me on something I have never understood with how you handle parameter types in dynamic languages vs. a static language (my perspective being informed or deformed - as you prefer) from Java.

Given a method foo that takes a parameter bar in a dynamic language, there is no enforcement at compile time of the type of bar. The answer linked above (and the answer I have generally seen to this) is that you need to unit test properly in a dynamic language.

But at some point something outside the unit will call that method. Say this is a heavy weight object that will be mocked in any unit tests of classes that use it. Now you have many classes which call this method, and you need to change the type. To keep it simple, it used to take a number, but now requires an alpha numeric, and you need to use a method specifically available on string and not on a number object with the new requirement.

How do you change it and know the calling code will be fixed? Sure if you just change it, your unit tests will fail, but since you need to change it on purpose, you would ostensibly fix your unit tests. How do you know to fix the calling code? I don't just mean how conceptually do you know, I mean how do you know you have found all the callers and can really say it is changed.

It would seem that only very comprehensive integration tests would give you that assurance. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've give an excellent concrete example of one of the advantages of static typing. Dynamic typing requires you to find all those call locations yourself. This is actually not very difficult though - its just a text search in your code. That's the trade-off: comfort that the compiler can cross-reference your code and make sure everything matches, vs not having distracting type tags throughout your code.

Comment: I guess this is the answer. I would just say that the type tags can be more of a burden that just distracting. I have spent a good amount of time "fixing" code strictly to satisfy the type system, not to mention duplicating code because of it.

Comment: Don't judge static typing by Java. Its type system is powerful enough to annoy you but not powerful enough to help you out much. You should at least check out OCaml.

Answer (score 2):

I need 15 characters to post, but the answer is four characters long:  grep.

Comment: +1. Static vs. dynamic is all about trade-offs. You get some stuff, you have to let go of some stuff. Easy refactoring is one of them. However, I don't think the answer is 4 chars long. It is simply ack these days. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Code defensively. Make the change backwards compatible in the new method. Dispatch on the type of the argument; [CLOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System) makes this easy.
2. Use a "who calls" function of your editor or IDE.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more of a refactoring question than a unit test question.

Parameters are effectively unit tested by insuring all properties and methods that are needed in a particular function are present and return the expected result. It is the interface that matters not the type.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is just 'more unit tests all the way up'.

the only thing that matters is that the new type also has the methods required. So if `ClassA` has Method1() which takes a param `obj` and invokes `obj#M1()` and `obj#M2()` - the only constraint on obj is that it responds to these messages. If you change the implementation to invoke a method `Foo()` which did not exist previously`, the tests exercising Class A fail.

Next if `ClassB` calls `A#Method1()` as part of its functionality, its tests will fail if Class B is passing an obj, which does have the required methods. If the required behavior of B isn't achieved, its tests should fail and that should direct towards changes needed in B.

Comment: Thanks, but that is why I explicity gave the case of a heavy object - say one that does database access, that you would have to mock to have a reasonable unit test.

Comment: ok.. so you're questions since we dont have strongly typed interfaces in dynamic languages, how do we ensure that the real object supports the same set of messages ? I'd say have some acceptance tests which use the real collaborator - not in your test suite that is executed every sec.. but one that is executed on a daily basis.

Comment: I don't think strongly coupling classes is a good solution. Even if it makes testing easier it will make the code spaghettier.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic language developers need to replicate the advantages of static typing, that is, by having that tools can automatically find those errors. For the most part, this involves type inference tools. The inference itself is pretty difficult (I'm writing my PhD on doing it for PHP) but using the tools isn't terribly difficult.

There are error finding tools for:

- Ruby: [Diamondback Ruby](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/druby/).
- Python: [pyntch](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pyntch/index.html)
- Javascript: [a tool has been built](http://www.brics.dk/TAJS/), but I don't see it for download.

For PHP, [phc](http://phpcompiler.org) could do this with a very small amount of work.

Overall, when you don't have static typing, you need a tool to get the benefits.